# The logic behind writing a Fibonacci sequence in C

Tags: c, fibonacci

- when returning (num-2) + (num-1) if num > 1 , the program works but I don't get it.
- when num is 0 write 0 and when num is 1 write 1.
- when num is 2, so (2-2) + (2-1), program will write 1
- but when num is 3, so (3-2) + (3-1), this equals 3 and the program write 2,
- the same when num is 4, (4-2) + (4-1) equals 5 and it writes 3 and not 5.
- I just wanna understand the logic behind it as I am new to programing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fibonacci_series(int num);
int main()
{
   int count, c = 0, i;
   printf("Enter number of terms:");
   scanf("%d",&count);
 
   printf("\nFibonacci series:\n");
   for ( i = 1 ; i <= count ; i++ )
   {
      printf("%d\n", fibonacci_series(c));
      c++; 
   }
 
   return 0;
}
int fibonacci_series(int num)
{
   if ( num == 0 )
     return 0;
   else if ( num == 1 )
     return 1;
   else
     return ( fibonacci_series(num-1) + fibonacci_series(num-2) );
}
```

Comment: Your understanding of the recursion is incorrect: the argument is for the **term** not its value. Your arithmetic `(4-2) + (4-1)` is on the **term** number, instead of their **value**. So term 4 will be term(4-2) + term(4-1), not (4-2) + (4-1).

Comment: thanks for the comment, and yes still confused with recursion.

Answer (score 2):

With the recursive solution, the evaluation looks something like this (I’m going to use `f` as the function name just to save me some typing):

```
f(3) ==
f(2)        + f(1) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) ==
1    + 0    + 1 ==
2
```

`f(3)` calls `f(2)` and `f(1)`.  `f(2)` calls `f(1)` and `f(0)`.

```
f(4) ==
f(3)               + f(2) ==
f(2) + f(1)        + f(2) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(1) + f(0) ==
1    + 0    + 1    + 1    + 0 ==
3

f(5) ==
f(4)                             + f(3) ==
f(3) + f(2)                      + f(3) ==
f(2) + f(1) + f(2)               + f(3) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(2)        + f(3) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(1) + f(0) + f(3) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(1) + f(0) + f(2) + f(1) ==
f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(0) + f(1) ==
1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 ==
5
```

Each `f(n)` *calls* `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)` and adds their results.

This is why the recursive implementation of fibonacci is so inefficient - it winds up computing the same values multiple times (many, many times as `n` gets large).  As a *definition* *F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub>* is nice and compact, but it’s not a good way to compute it.

Comment: Great :D, thanks for giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

Given a num that's not 0 nor 1, the function calls itself:

```c
fibonacci_series(num-1) + fibonacci_series(num-2)
```

So, when num is 2, the program does ***not*** do `(2-2) + (2-1)` like you indicated in your question:

- *when num is 2, so (2-2) + (2-1), program will write 1*

Instead, substituting 2 as `num`, it actually does this:

```c
fibonacci_series(2-1) + fibonacci_series(2-2)
```

To evaluate this, the function calls have to be made first before the `+`.

`fibonacci_series(2-1)` is same as `fibonacci_series(1)` which gets you the value `1`.

`fibonacci_series(2-2)` is same as `fibonacci_series(0)` which gets you the value `0`.

Add `1` and `0` and that's the reason you get `1`. It's just a ***coincidence*** that this is same as `(2-2) + (2-1)`.

There is no such coincidence going from num=3 onwards:

```c
fibonacci_series(3-1) + fibonacci_series(3-2)
```

`fibonacci_series(3-1)` is same as `fibonacci_series(2)` and as observed above the value is `1`.

`fibonacci_series(3-2)` is same as `fibonacci_series(1)` and you get value `1`.

That's why the program writes `2` (which is actually `1` + `1`) instead of `3` as you thought it should be.

You can do the same kind of tracing for num=4 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still confused with this recursion, when num=3 onwards,

Comment: I expanded the text, so hope you can understand better.

Comment: it's super clear now, Thanks so much :D